# Best way to split Android permissions into multiple apps / plugins

Tags: android, plugins, permissions, rpc, aidl

I would like to add to my app the functionality "unread SMS count" which off course requires a new Android permissions, since not all my users will need that functionality I'd like to distribute it as a plugin in order to avoid having too many permissions on the main app.

Application is already in the market and i did not specify an "UID" when i first published it so the shared "UID" space is not an option.

So question is, which is the best way to do this? Is an AIDL remote service the only option i have? Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: I believe you could use a content provider in the plugin and use it from your main app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is an AIDL remote service the only option i have?

No.

> Is there any simpler solution?

Create a `ContentProvider` proxy for the (undocumented and unsupported) `ContentProvider` that you are trying to access.

The projects in [this directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/CPProxy) demonstrate such a proxy and a consumer of that proxy. In my case, I am proxying the `CallLog`, but the same concept applies for any `ContentProvider`.

The keys are:

- Have the plugin hold the desired permission for the `ContentProvider` it is proxying
- Have both the app and the plugin define a custom signature-level permission to be used by such plugins (`<permission>`)
- Have the app hold that permission (`<uses-permission>`)
- Have the plugin protect the `ContentProvider` proxy via that custom permission (`android:permission`)

This will allow your app to access the plugin's `ContentProvider` proxy, while not leaking the capability of accessing the proxied `ContentProvider` to others.

Comment: Looks much more elegant than the AIDL approach! I will test it out and mark as resolved if it works but useful anyway!

Comment: Works and same approach can also be used for broadcast receivers (es the "call" permission) so its quite flexible, thanks a lot